# How to save multipart form data to a file in AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, multipartform-data, aws-serverless

I am writing a serverless api using Node.js and Typescript. I want to send a .xlsx file from the client side and save the file in S3 bucket.
I tried using the npm package [busboy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/busboy). And the file that saved in S3 bucket cannot be read(corrupted or not written fully). Looks like I haven't write the file correctly.
Here's my code

```js
    import * as busboy from 'busboy';
    import AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    import { S3 } from 'aws-sdk';

    export const saveExcel: Handler = (event: APIGatewayEvent, context: Context, cb: Callback) => {

          const contentType = event.headers['Content-Type'] || event.headers['content-type'];
          const bb: busboy.Busboy = new busboy({ headers: { 'content-type': contentType } });

          bb.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
            file
              .on('data', data => {
                const params: S3.PutObjectRequest = {
                  Bucket: 'bucket-name',
                  Key: filename,
                  Body: data
                };
                s3.upload(params, function (err, data) {
                  if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                  } else {
                    console.log(data);
                  }
                })
              })
              .on('end', () => {
                console.log("done");
              });
          });

          bb.end(event.body);
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? Or do I have to try any other library?

Comment: Your way - upload file to S3 via Lambda function is not recommended. In my opinion, you can use lambda function to generate  s3 signed link, return the link to client, client upload the file via the signed link(Direct to S3 File Uploads way)

Comment: @hoangdv I can't do that in my scenario. I need the REST API to handle this part.

Comment: `Body` field of `s3.upload` 's param need a Base64String not a stream data. Good luck!

Comment: The on data handler may be invoked multiple times with partial data, please debug and check if it is your case. As well there's a limit in payload length for lambda (I believe it is 6MB).

Comment: @gusto2 I have tried it. It's invoked only one time.

Comment: @hoangdv any idea how to convert data?

Comment: to encode/decode you can just search, e.g. [here](https://www.hacksparrow.com/base64-encoding-decoding-in-node-js.html) is a nice blog. Though as far I know you should be able to use the stream too, so I am not so sure there's no another issue